# How to save to web with an hyperlink (slice tool) in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, save

I have added an hyperlink to a QR Code in Photoshop CC using the slice tool.

Now I want to save my file in 2 differents formats

As a JPEG to post on social media
As an JPEG in html format to insert on our website

Soooo...since I am new in doing all of this, I really need some help here.
I have to make this illustration available tomorrow morning the latest and have spend so many hours trying and researching the web for answers and how to.

Can someone help me in the step by step to do that.
Every time I try, it either creates multiples files that are "pieces" of my original illustration or when I try in html format and I try to load the page afterwards by clicking on the saved *.html file, it doesn't load the image !

Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 2):

Images **can't** contain links within themselves. That's not how images work.

In order to have a "link" you **must** use some surrounding HTML markup.

Like this:
`<a href="yourlink.com"><img src="YourImageHere.jpg" /></a>`

**There is no way to make just a jpg, png, or gif that is also a link.**

There's such thing as a "JPEG in html format". A jpeg is in jpeg format.

I am not familiar with Facebook uploading, but I imagine if you are selecting an .html file when trying to upload an *image*, the web site would not accept the upload. In all probability the web site *expects* to see a .jpg, .png or .gif file.

Comment: Hummmm.....well, when you go in "save for web".  You get a nice "preview" option that lets you test your image with the imbeded link.

Comment: Yes.. because it's using surrounding HTML to make the link.. it is previewing a **web page** for you, not just the image. which is why you get an .html file when you click save. :) You don't have to believe me...... I'm just trying to help,  you're free to continue chasing unicorns and leprechauns. :)

Comment: It works fine when I click on preview, it does open my browser with my nice illustration and when I click on the QR Code, it does open nicely in a new page like I specified in the "slice tool options".  So If I could just get some help on how to finish the saving options at the end it would make my day.  There is lots of tutorials explaining how to include an hyperlink like I did using the slice tool options.  I guess I will eventually get my answer.

Comment: Will try to contact 2 of my other designer friends tomorrow...still waiting for replies to my email I send them.  Hope to be able to enlightened other people that like me, want to know the steps in saving for web with imbeded hyperlinks.

Comment: If anyone wants a nice tutorial on how to add hyperlinks using the slice tool in photoshop, just let me know and it will be my pleasure to help ;)

Comment: Slicing an image creates a **web page** populated by HTML markup and images, not an image itself, as I've explained. Good luck in your search.. apparently you feel I have no clue what I'm posting about.

Comment: @Scott.....hahaha....of course I want to believe you, curiosity is also a sign of intelligence, so sorry if I keep pushing the subject and chasing "unicorns and leprechauns"...we never know I might find one ! hahaha !

Comment: So, this being said, how do others do it ? How do they publish an illustration with an imbeded hyperlink ?  If the solution is not in photoshop I guess there is definitely a solution and maybe my question is not for photoshop.  For the web page I am not to worry, because I have the option to create the code.....it's really for other plateforms that I am wondering how to do it.  We are all here to exchange knowledge and learn from others, so again thank you for your answer, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: **No one** literally **no one** creates a jpg with an embedded link. It's not possible with current technology. They use HTML markup around the jpg. How it's done on Facebook.. well that's a Facebook help question I can't really assist with.

Comment: Hyperlinks are an HTML feature, not a jpeg feature. If you are seeing hyperlinks on images in webpages they have an HTML code around them, or a javascript that adds a link around said image, even on Facebook or google or whatever. Either way, it won't work straight out of Photoshop with just the .jpg file.

Comment: Why do I find this conversation sooo amusing ? :))